# Projects to understand Numerical Methods

Tags: numerical-methods

I am a physicist by education and I am doing a PhD right now. Although, knowing numerical methods is not essential in my field, it would still help me understand it better.

Just reading introductory books on numerical methods is to dry and boring for me. I need some applications. Therefore, I am looking for projects on a timescale of weeks to months, which would keep me going forward in studying numerical methods.

Do you have some ideas? I am thinking of something like the guy, who used neural networks to train bots in Quake 3; this sounds like fun for me.

Cheers :)

Comment: I used, for example, interpolations to predict some social games parameters behavior (based on known\observed values) to optimize my team game. Some people used some statistics and data mining techniques for similar tasks.

Comment: If you find a way to use ODEs or PDEs in such a funny way - I with you!

Comment: Do you mean to find ODEs/PDEs, which discribes the behavior in the game and then to solve them numerically?

Comment: this could be good example, but may be not the only one, dunno, never really thought about this

Comment: Write a physics engine! Rigid bodies are relatively easy to implement. If you are looking for a challenge try fluid dynamics.